# How to automatically transfer data

Tags: matlab, csv

I have thousands of csv files and they basically have 2 formats. One type of 2 formats is that in those csv files there are 100 rows and 2 columns. The other type of csv files has 50 columns and 5 rows. The numbers are given just to provide an example.

What I want to do is to write a Matlab code that will extract the complete second row of the csv files with the first format and make it the first row of the csv files with the second format. The number of the csv files with the first and second format is equal.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: How are the files named? Do they follow a standard naming procedure that distinguishes one type of file from the other?

Comment: Yes, two different formats can be distinguished by the extensions of the files. The extension of the first format is -00001.csv and of the second format is -00001.abc. (just to give you an example)

Comment: It's not possible because you want to extract a vector that is `1x2` (from a matrix that is `100x2`) and insert it into a matrix that is `5x50`. There is a mismatch in the number of columns between your extracted vector and the destination matrix where you want to insert it.